# Distributing as a standalone executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, cx-freeze, software-distribution

I have been developing an application using Python 3.3 and PyQt4 and I would like to be able to distribute it as a standalone app. My development environment is OS X and I have been able to create a standalone OS X app using cx_Freeze and py2app.

My question is, how would I go about creating an executable file for windows, considering I do not have access to a Windows operating system for development?

I have tried using cx_Freeze's build_exe on OS X and running it on windows but it will not run.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: cx_Freeze can't do that - to make a Windows exe, you need to freeze on Windows. However, you might be able to use a new project of mine, [pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). That will make a Windows installer that installs Python and your code and creates start menu shortcuts. You'll need to install NSIS - it looks like both macports and homebrew have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use pyinstaller to create stand alone exe for windows.  http://www.pyinstaller.org/.